# Blender Grease pencils glow effect in any specific layer or region

Tags: grease-pencil, effects

Is there an option to limit the effects like BLUR and GLOW to a specific part of a compound scene (when multiple elements in one view)? whenever I tried applying that it applied to the whole scene. Is there any shader mask or such things?

I have discovered that the effects in different objects only work if the objects are present as separate "Greasepencil objects" like 2 stroke layers (which appears in the collection).

Comment: I think you will have to use different grease pencil objects. You can kind of hack your way to emulate glow or blur with specific layers and modifiers but I don't think it's designed to be used that way. It's very easy to make different objects share materials or layers though

Comment: Hello, yes I have already mentioned the solution as you stated in the question. Creating a grease pencil object isn't tuff, but when someone is doing animation it is hard to switch between grease pencil objects, so it will be more appreciable if a separate masking layer made available for the effects layer. *Please consider I am saying in context to 2d animation